# plot in all the subplots at the same time

Tags: matlab, subplot

I have a figure with 2 subplots. 
I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to draw the same plots in all the subplots at the same time.

For example in the following plot I'd like to plot (x,y) simultaneously and then proceed separately.

```
fig1 = figure
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,y)
hold on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,y)
hold on

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,z)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,k)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `set` using cell arrays as follows. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/set.html) for details.

```
subplot(2,1,1);
h1 = plot(x,y); %// get a handle to the plot
subplot(2,1,2)
h2 = plot(x,y); %// get a handle to the plot

set([h1; h2], {'xdata'}, {x1; x2}, {'ydata'}, {y1; y2})
%// new values: x1 x2 y1 y2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking because you want to plot the same plot behind say 16 subplots, then you could do it in a loop:

```
for k= 1:16
    s(k) = subplot(4,4,k);
    plot(x,y);
    hold on;
end
```

If you just want it for 2 subplots then there is nothing wrong with your current code

Comment: yes, I have to plot the same plot in several subplots, but I thought there was a way to "link" the subplots like for the axes and then avoid the loop...